# Grails 3 - springSecurity reauthenticate and SessionRegistry

Tags: authentication, grails, spring-security, grails3

My Grails application (powered with Spring Security plugin) has in place a very basic support a 'quick login' feature, basically prompting users to type only their password to login while `userId` is stored in an encrypted cookie.

So in my controller I'm using 
`springSecurityService.reauthenticate(userid)`
to authenticate the user manually.

My application has also the requirement of not allowing concurrent sessions. So, along with the previous line, I added

```
def authentication = SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication
def sessions = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(authentication.getPrincipal(), false)
// [L]
sessions.each {
    it.expireNow()
}
```

The issue is that these reauthentications do not reflect in an entry in `sessionRegistry`, and that's an issue with the above code, as among `sessions` I wouldn't find any session for that user.

The problem I'm not currently able to resolve is:

- user [U] logs in to location [A]
- [U] logs in to location [B] => session [A] is forced to expire
- [U] keeps on navigating/refreshes [A], and is prompted to quick login
- [U] logs in again to [A] => `reauthenticate` is triggered, nothing is added to `sessionRegistry`
- [U] keeps on navigating/refreshes [B], and is prompted to quick login
- [U] logs in again to [B]
- [U] is logged on both [A] and [B]

I also tried to add
`sessionRegistry.registerNewSession(newSessionId, authentication.getPrincipal())`
in `[L]` position, but this session and the regenerated one seem to be not related in any way.

Any suggestion is welcome! Thanks in advance.

*Config*

- Grails 3.2.4
- Spring Security Plugin (core) 3.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few attempts I came up with a working solution

```
// injected dependencies
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager
SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy

// code
Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.email, params.password))
SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication = authResult   // need to reassign to context, otherwise onAuthentication fails (wrong password)
sessionAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(authResult, request, response)
```

The trick seems to be calling `onAuthentication`, triggering all the defined request filters, on which relies the my concurrency session management.